# Why is the composition of either an odd or an even function with an even function even, but not vice versa?

Tags: functions

This is a statement from wikipedia. I don't understand what the "but not vice versa" part means. Does it mean that the composition of even or odd function with even is *not* odd (can only be even)? Or does it mean that the composition of even function with odd is not necessarily even? If it's the latter, then I don't understand how it works, please give examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that in general you should be careful with wikipedia articles on very elementary subjects, they are likely to be written by a low-level student with an imperfect understanding. So if something does not make a lot of sense, it may be just wrong.

Here I guess that the author wanted to say that even though "even $\circ$ even/odd = even", you don't have "odd $\circ$ even/odd = odd". Which is pretty obvious since the two are clearly incompatible.

Comment: That's why I wish people just wrote things using the language of math and not English words, that can be ambiguous...Thanks!